# ¿como puedo eliminar todos los elementos de un vector?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

El programa que hago es de un restaurante, una vez que se realiza el pedido, e imprime factura y esas cosas, quiero que se eliminen los datos almacenados en mi vector.

Comment: Hola Fabio, bienvenido a [es.so], tengo algunas preguntas, ¿a qué te refieres con eliminar los datos almacenados de tu vector? ¿qué es un vector, algo así como una lista genérica? Recuerda que entre más detalles será más sencillo encontrar una solución a tu problema. Sugiero que agregues el código con el cual trabajas actualmente, eso nos dará un panorama más amplio de cómo dar una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: con lo que muestra quizas lo que usted busca lo puede lograr usando `clear` sobre el vector en cuestion en el momento que precise. puede mirar aqui http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/ bienvenido a stackoverflow. Saludos